# How come I am not able to run my cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, bdd

I am a newbie for RoR, and I am taking a look into BDD with cucumber during these days.

However, I am stock by a trivial problem. I have completely operated according to this post: http://www.mattvsworld.com/blog/2010/02/ruby-1-9-rails-2-3-5-and-cucumber/ But I still get this:

```
Couldn't find 'cucumber' generator
```

Then I uninstalled/installed cucumber-rails a lot of rounds with **sudo** and still get this:

```
Couldn't find 'cucumber' generator
```

I am speculating that my cucumber-rails is not in the path. Since I get this with `cucumber-rails -version`

> -bash: cucumber-rails: command not found

Can anyone tell me what I should do now?

Comment: What version of rails are you using? If rails 3, have you added cucumber to your gemfile and run `bundle install` ?

Comment: It's Rails 2.3.5. So I think I don't have to run 'bundle install'. By the way, I am using mac os.

Comment: try 'gem list cucumber-rails'

Comment: the output: *** LOCAL GEMS *** cucumber-rails (1.0.2)
I think I really got cucumber-rails installed.

Comment: how about "gem list cucumber" ?

Comment: the output: *** LOCAL GEMS ***

cucumber (1.0.0)
cucumber-rails (1.0.2)

This is supposed to be correct, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have solved the problem. It turns out that cucumber-rails (1.0.2) does not work very well with Rails 2.3.5. It has to be Rails 3.x.x.

So, once I reverted cucumber-rails back to v 0.3.2. It worked like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

Very useful information @Winston Chen. The suggestion to Revert cucumber-rails to v 0.3.2 solved a similar problem for me for a Rails 2.3.12 app.

To solve I simply did the following `gem uninstall cucumber-rails -v 1.0.2` 
and then using bundler installed `gem 'cucumber-rails', '~> 0.3.2'`

Comment: Relevant info to the problem of being unable to find the cucumber generator can be found here https://github.com/carlhuda/bundler/issues/210